# how to configure Gradle release build?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I developed an application, everything worked until it took me to change the package. I did this debug version going, release version going. When launched on the device it turns off, I looked in the logs and wrote there:

```
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you’re either running a metro server (or 'run-native-start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged for release."
```

How to fix it, maybe when changing a package, I forgot to change something (I changed the search with auto-replacement)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3RFp.png)

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace or is that it?

Comment: Just to be sure, did you rename the `applicationId` value within your `android {...}` closure when you renamed the package?

Comment: yes, i change applicationId

Comment: Can we see some code? Can you revert the package name change to ensure that there's not something else going on?